# how can I properly exclude files from rsync

Tags: rsync

I currently have a script which should do an rsync of one specific subdirectory of several directories on a remote server.

On the remote server I have several `/home/USERDIR/inbox` and want to rsync the inboxes to my local `inboxes/USERDIR/inbox`. The commandline I use is:

```bash
PARTNER='user1,user2,user3'
rsync -rv --include inbox --exclude '.?*' "$REMOTE:$REMOTEHOME/{$PARTNER}" inboxes/
```

Unfortunately one of the "users" has files in their homedirectory so that I do not only sync the inbox, but also those files.

I seem to be unable to figure out how to properly exclude all files but the inbox files.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The include / exclude has to be:

```bash
--include='inbox/*' --exclude='*/*[^inbox]'
```